# storing login page locally in device using phonegap

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

Planning to use phoneGap for our web app which runs on android and iOS.
To reduce initial loading of the page faster, planning to add login page as a part of phonegap itself.
So that login page will be fetched from device itself instead of hitting service and bringing it.
How to add login as apart of webview?